# how to add postgresql database from file

Tags: database, postgresql, directory, pgadmin

Basically when creating new database, PostgreSQL make directory in "data/base" with OID. 
Now I have a directory like this from my previous database, can i import this directory as a real database in pgAdmin?

I have a folder from my old database called 16384.I past it in my data/base folder but pgAdmin does not recognize it as a database.
I want to import it in my Pgadmin.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

no. you can't do it with pgadmin.
try starting postgres with your data_directory `pg_ctl -D DIR_WITH_BASE_CATALOG`. If you lucky to star it, you can try taking a full backup - if success, the directory is usable, if not, you would recommend asking experts to help you extract as much as possible. If you decide to use `zero_damaged_pages` or other advanced features you can irreversibly destroy data (if there still is what to destroy)

anyway, before you start, I'd recommend copying the whole data_directory to somewhere else, and trying to start cluster from copy, not original...

Comment: How can i use pg_ctl -D?
When i use "pg_ctl -D C:\maria\Data\base\16384" it return:
"pg_ctl: no operation specified"

Comment: try `pg_ctl -D C:\maria\Data start`